# How can I test if files given as an argument exist?

Tags: bash, while-loop, arguments

I am making a bash script that you have to give 2 files or more as arguments.
I want to test if the given files exist. I'm using a `while` loop because I don't know how many files are given. The problem is that the if statement sees the `$t` as a number and not as the positional parameter `$number`. Does somebody have a solution?

```
t=1
max=$#
while [ $t -le $max ]; do

    if [ ! -f $t ]; then
            echo "findmagic.sh: $t is not a regular file"
            echo "Usage: findmagic.sh file file ...."
            exit
    fi

    t=`expr $t + 1`
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the [bash Special parameter `@`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) in this way:

```
script_name=${0##*/}
for t in "$@"; do
    if [ ! -f "$t" ]; then
        echo "$script_name: $t is not a regular file"
        echo "Usage: $script_name file file ...."
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

With `"$@"` you are expanding the positional parameters, starting from **one** as separate words (your arguments).

---

Besides, remember to provide a meaningful exit status (e.g. `exit 1` instead of `exit` alone). If not provided, the exit status is that of the last command executed (`echo` in your case, which succes, so you're `exit`ing with **0**).

And for last, instead of write the script name (**findmagic.sh** in your case), you can set a variable at the beginning in your script:

```
script_name=${0##*/}
```

and then use `$script_name` when necessary. In this way you don't need to update your script if it changes its name.